# Which RadioButton in a group is checked (Google AppScript)

Tags: radio-button, google-apps-script, radio-group

Using Google AppScript. How could I find the checked RadioButton in a group? If it requires handler then with server one.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is an [open issue](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=506#c14) on this but there is also a nice workaround ;-)  (found by Romain Vialard, GAS TC)

here is a slightly modified version of his script adapted to run on a spreadsheet :

```
function radiotest() {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();
  var panel = app.createVerticalPanel();
  var radioValue = app.createTextBox();
     radioValue.setId("radioValue").setName("radioValue");               
  // var radioValue = app.createHidden().setName("radioValue") ;// choose the one you like
  for(var i = 1; i < 10; i++){
    var name = 'choice '+i;
    var handler = app.createClientHandler().forTargets(radioValue).setText(name);
    panel.add(app.createRadioButton('radioButtonGroup',name).addValueChangeHandler(handler));
  }
  panel.add(radioValue);
  var Valide=app.createButton("Valide").setId("val");
  panel.add(Valide)                   
  app.add(panel);
//               
  var handler = app.createServerHandler("valide"); // this is the server handler
  handler.addCallbackElement(radioValue)
  Valide.addClickHandler(handler);
//
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().show(app);// show app 
    }
    //
function valide(e){ ;// This function is called when key "validate" is pressed 
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var RadioButton = e.parameter.radioValue;               
  sh.getRange('A1').setValue(RadioButton);
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  return app;
}​
```

Note that the radioValue item can be either a textbox or a hidden text, both possibilities are in the script/

Comment: Many thanks Serge for both the code and the open issue source.

Comment: I didn't know about the vertical panel and UIapp -- thanks.

Comment: UiApp has been deprecated a long time ago, you can not use it anymore. But thanks for your comment :)